# Dist::Zilla - detect missing/uninstallable prereqs

Tags: perl, release, dist-zilla

Is there a Dist::Zilla plugin which will make "dzil build" (or "dzil release") check that all prerequisites are actually met on the build system?

Merely building successfully is not enough, because there can be dependencies in the generated META.yaml which can never be met when the package is later installed by others.

For example (this happened to me):  The code contains

```
  if ($^O eq "MSWin32") {
    require Win32API::Net;
    ...do something...
  }
```

and in dist.ini

```
[OSPrereqs / MSWin32]
Win32API::Net = 0
```

But what I failed to do was tell `AutoPreqs` to not
make Win32API::Net an unconditional build requirement (by adding `skip = ^Win32API::`).

Since Win32API is *only* installable on Windows, the distribution could not be installed on Linux.  And to my chagrin I did not find out until after the new release hit CPAN!

Is there a way I can prevent such things happening?

If `dzil release` checked that all "requires" listed in the generated META.yaml are met, it would have found the mistake before pushing a broken release to CPAN.  It might also detect that the release was being tested with insufficiently-recent versions of required modules.

Comment: You can release a dev version, allowing the smokers to have a go at it before the proper release.

Comment: A question your fix. It sounds like it will now fail to install on Windows unless someone happens to have Win32API::Net already installed.

Comment: So what is the correct way, if not by using Dist::Zilla::Plugin::OSPrereqs ?

Comment: No idea. Never used Dist::Zilla